# Eigen compile errors: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, qt5, eigen

I am trying to use Eigen 3.2.2 in a Qt5 project that is being compiled on a win32 Vista machine. The code that uses the Eigen library compiles just fine on my OSX computer when setup as a simple C++ project. I get the following two errors when I add it to the Qt project on the Windows machine:

```
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:198: error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::internal::blas_traits<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<float>, const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > > > >::extract(const type&)'
   static inline ExtractType extract(const XprType& x) { return Base::extract(x.nestedExpression()); }
                                                                                                  ^
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:198: candidate is:
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:169: static const XprType& Eigen::internal::blas_traits<XprType>::extract(const XprType&) [with XprType = Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > >; Eigen::internal::blas_traits<XprType>::ExtractType = const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > >&]
   static inline ExtractType extract(const XprType& x) { return x; }
                             ^
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:169: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const type {aka const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 0, 4, 4>}' to 'const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > >&'
```

```
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:200: error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::internal::blas_traits<Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_multiple_op<float>, const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > > > >::extractScalarFactor(const type&)'
{ return x.functor().m_other * Base::extractScalarFactor(x.nestedExpression()); }
                                                                            ^
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:200: candidate is:
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:170: static const Scalar Eigen::internal::blas_traits<XprType>::extractScalarFactor(const XprType&) [with XprType = Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > >; Eigen::internal::blas_traits<XprType>::Scalar = float]
static inline const Scalar extractScalarFactor(const XprType&) { return Scalar(1); }
                           ^
<ProjectDir>\3rdParty\eigen-3.2.2\Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:170: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const type {aka const Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1, 0, 4, 4>}' to 'const Eigen::ReturnByValue<Eigen::internal::inverse_impl<Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4>, -1, -1, false> > >&'
```

The errors point to the lines marked below in Eigen\src\Core\util\BlasUtil.h:

```
// pop scalar multiple
template<typename Scalar, typename NestedXpr>
struct blas_traits<CwiseUnaryOp<scalar_multiple_op<Scalar>, NestedXpr> >
 : blas_traits<NestedXpr>
{
  typedef blas_traits<NestedXpr> Base;
  typedef CwiseUnaryOp<scalar_multiple_op<Scalar>, NestedXpr> XprType;
  typedef typename Base::ExtractType ExtractType;
// Error 1 on following line
  static inline ExtractType extract(const XprType& x) { return Base::extract(x.nestedExpression()); }
  static inline Scalar extractScalarFactor(const XprType& x)
// Error 2 on following line
  { return x.functor().m_other * Base::extractScalarFactor(x.nestedExpression()); }
};
```

What would cause these errors? I'm very new to C++ and even more so to Qt and Qt Creator so I may have missed something basic. If that is the case please point me in the right direction and I'll start digging. Thanks!

Edit:

The lines that seem to trigger the errors looks like this:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f mat1;
Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> mat2, result;
// fill and work with matrices...
result = -1.0 * mat1.topLeftCorner(3, 3).transpose() * mat2 // PROBLEM LINE
```

Comment: Hard to give an exact answer without seeing the entire project. Seems to be an issue with missing includes or include-order problems.

Comment: @Silicomancer That's what I was thinking, but BlasUtil.h has no includes. Everything it uses, it defines and implements within itself.

Comment: Adding parentheses around the matrix multiplication expression before multiplying by -1 seems to have fixed it.